# Make files dump into a fence by default

Tags: fences

I want to make any files that get dumped onto my desktop go into an "Unfiled" or "Misc" fence by default with Fences, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wish this existed as well, but unfortunately auto-fencing is not yet supported. It doesn't hurt to [send in a request](http://www.stardock.com/about/contactus.asp) for it though!

Comment: That would be even more awesome ;-)